# Proper command to upload XML to datatable in SQL Server database after opening connection?

Tags: sql-server, xml, vb.net

I am testing some bit of code that I am implementing to pull from an XML file and place into a database. I have successfully written to the XML file without issue. The only issue that is now presenting itself is uploading the information successfully from the XML file to the SQL Server database table.

Running the code as a query successfully places the XML information into the datatable.

However when implemented into code I cannot get it to function.

I know to open the connection, but I am unfamiliar with the correct command to insert the data from the XML file to the DataTable in the specified SQL Server database.

What would be the correct command that I am missing? Or is there something else I'm missing?

If more information is needed upon request I can list the contents of the entire code.

Every other facet of the code is operating as should at this point and even generates the XML file to import into the database without issue.  I only have an issue of properly importing the XML information into the datatable thorough the connection set up within the code.

Thank you for your time and review in this matter.

Full code listed here:

```vb
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Module Module1

    Public Sub Main()

        Dim dt As New DataTable("DriveInformation")

        Dim Column_1st As New DataColumn("Date")
        Dim Column_2nd As New DataColumn("Server")
        Dim Column_3rd As New DataColumn("Drive")
        Dim Column_4th As New DataColumn("TotalSpace")
        Dim Column_5th As New DataColumn("UsedSpace")
        Dim Column_6th As New DataColumn("RemainingSpace")
        Dim Column_7th As New DataColumn("GBorTBDrive")
        Dim Column_8th As New DataColumn("DriveActiveStatus")

        dt.Columns.Add(Column_1st)
        dt.Columns.Add(Column_2nd)
        dt.Columns.Add(Column_3rd)
        dt.Columns.Add(Column_4th)
        dt.Columns.Add(Column_5th)
        dt.Columns.Add(Column_6th)
        dt.Columns.Add(Column_7th)
        dt.Columns.Add(Column_8th)

        ' Get information and Write to Console.

        Console.WriteLine("Server Name: {0}", System.Net.Dns.GetHostName)
        Console.WriteLine("Date: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt"))
        Console.WriteLine("")

        Dim DriveNumber As Integer = 0
        Dim allDrives() As IO.DriveInfo = IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives()
        Dim d As IO.DriveInfo

        For Each d In allDrives
            Dim DriveName As String = d.Name
            DriveNumber = DriveNumber + 1
            Console.WriteLine(DriveName)
            Console.WriteLine("  Drive type: {0}", d.DriveType)
            If d.IsReady = True And d.TotalSize < 1099511627776 Then
                Console.WriteLine("  Volume label: {0}", d.VolumeLabel)
                Console.WriteLine("  File system: {0}", d.DriveFormat)
                Console.WriteLine(
                "  Total size of drive:   {0, 15} GB ",
                FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024))

            ElseIf d.IsReady = True And d.TotalSize >= 1099511627776 Then
                Console.WriteLine("  Volume label: {0}", d.VolumeLabel)
                Console.WriteLine("  File system: {0}", d.DriveFormat)

                Console.WriteLine(
                "  Total size of drive:   {0, 15} TB ",
                FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024))
            End If

            If d.IsReady = True And d.TotalSize - d.TotalFreeSpace < 1099511627776 Then
                Console.WriteLine(
                    "  Total used space:      {0, 15} GB",
                FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024))

            ElseIf d.IsReady = True And d.TotalSize - d.TotalFreeSpace >= 1099511627776 Then
                Console.WriteLine(
                    "  Total used space:      {0, 15} TB",
                    FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024))
            End If

            If d.IsReady = True And d.TotalFreeSpace < 1099511627776 Then
                Console.WriteLine(
                    "  Total available space: {0, 15} GB",
                    FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024))
                Console.WriteLine("")

            ElseIf d.IsReady = True And d.TotalFreeSpace >= 1099511627776 Then
                Console.WriteLine(
                "  Total available space: {0, 15} TB",
                FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024))
                Console.WriteLine("")

            End If
        Next

        ' Put Information into DataTable
        For Each d In allDrives
            Dim DriveName As String = d.Name

            If DriveNumber = 1 And d.TotalSize < 1099511627776 Then

                Dim drow1 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

                drow1("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt")
                drow1("Server") = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
                drow1("Drive") = DriveName.Remove(1, 2)
                drow1("TotalSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow1("UsedSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow1("RemainingSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow1("GBorTBDrive") = "GB"
                drow1("DriveActiveStatus") = d.IsReady
                dt.Rows.Add(drow1)

            ElseIf DriveNumber = 1 And d.TotalSize >= 1099511627776 And d.TotalSize - d.TotalFreeSpace >= 1099511627776 And d.TotalFreeSpace >= 1099511627776 Then

                Dim drow1 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

                drow1("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt")
                drow1("Server") = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
                drow1("Drive") = DriveName.Remove(1, 2)
                drow1("TotalSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow1("UsedSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow1("RemainingSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow1("GBorTBDrive") = "TB"
                drow1("DriveActiveStatus") = d.IsReady
                dt.Rows.Add(drow1)

            ElseIf DriveNumber = 1 And d.TotalSize >= 1099511627776 And d.TotalSize - d.TotalFreeSpace >= 1099511627776 And d.TotalFreeSpace < 1099511627776 Then

                Dim drow1 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

                drow1("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt")
                drow1("Server") = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
                drow1("Drive") = DriveName.Remove(1, 2)
                drow1("TotalSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024,)
                drow1("UsedSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow1("RemainingSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow1("GBorTBDrive") = "TB"
                drow1("DriveActiveStatus") = d.IsReady
                dt.Rows.Add(drow1)

            ElseIf DriveNumber = 1 And d.TotalSize >= 1099511627776 And d.TotalSize - d.TotalFreeSpace < 1099511627776 And d.TotalFreeSpace >= 1099511627776 Then

                Dim drow1 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

                drow1("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt")
                drow1("Server") = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
                drow1("Drive") = DriveName.Remove(1, 2)
                drow1("TotalSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024,)
                drow1("UsedSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow1("RemainingSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow1("GBorTBDrive") = "TB"
                drow1("DriveActiveStatus") = d.IsReady
                dt.Rows.Add(drow1)

            ElseIf DriveNumber = 1 And d.TotalSize >= 1099511627776 And d.TotalSize - d.TotalFreeSpace < 1099511627776 And d.TotalFreeSpace < 1099511627776 Then

                Dim drow1 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

                drow1("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt")
                drow1("Server") = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
                drow1("Drive") = DriveName.Remove(1, 2)
                drow1("TotalSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024,)
                drow1("UsedSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow1("RemainingSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow1("GBorTBDrive") = "TB"
                drow1("DriveActiveStatus") = d.IsReady
                dt.Rows.Add(drow1)

            End If

            If DriveNumber = 2 And d.TotalSize < 1099511627776 Then

                Dim drow2 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

                drow2("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt")
                drow2("Server") = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
                drow2("Drive") = DriveName.Remove(1, 2)
                drow2("TotalSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow2("UsedSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow2("RemainingSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow2("GBorTBDrive") = "GB"
                drow2("DriveActiveStatus") = d.IsReady
                dt.Rows.Add(drow2)

            ElseIf DriveNumber = 2 And d.TotalSize >= 1099511627776 And d.TotalSize - d.TotalFreeSpace >= 1099511627776 And d.TotalFreeSpace >= 1099511627776 Then

                Dim drow2 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

                drow2("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt")
                drow2("Server") = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
                drow2("Drive") = DriveName.Remove(1, 2)
                drow2("TotalSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow2("UsedSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow2("RemainingSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow2("GBorTBDrive") = "TB"
                drow2("DriveActiveStatus") = d.IsReady
                dt.Rows.Add(drow2)

            ElseIf DriveNumber = 2 And d.TotalSize >= 1099511627776 And d.TotalSize - d.TotalFreeSpace >= 1099511627776 And d.TotalFreeSpace < 1099511627776 Then

                Dim drow2 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

                drow2("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt")
                drow2("Server") = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
                drow2("Drive") = DriveName.Remove(1, 2)
                drow2("TotalSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow2("UsedSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow2("RemainingSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow2("GBorTBDrive") = "TB"
                drow2("DriveActiveStatus") = d.IsReady
                dt.Rows.Add(drow2)

            ElseIf DriveNumber = 2 And d.TotalSize >= 1099511627776 And d.TotalSize - d.TotalFreeSpace < 1099511627776 And d.TotalFreeSpace >= 1099511627776 Then

                Dim drow2 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

                drow2("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt")
                drow2("Server") = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
                drow2("Drive") = DriveName.Remove(1, 2)
                drow2("TotalSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow2("UsedSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow2("RemainingSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow2("GBorTBDrive") = "TB"
                drow2("DriveActiveStatus") = d.IsReady
                dt.Rows.Add(drow2)

            ElseIf DriveNumber = 2 And d.TotalSize >= 1099511627776 And d.TotalSize - d.TotalFreeSpace < 1099511627776 And d.TotalFreeSpace < 1099511627776 Then

                Dim drow2 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

                drow2("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt")
                drow2("Server") = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
                drow2("Drive") = DriveName.Remove(1, 2)
                drow2("TotalSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024,)
                drow2("UsedSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow2("RemainingSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow2("GBorTBDrive") = "TB"
                drow2("DriveActiveStatus") = d.IsReady
                dt.Rows.Add(drow2)

            End If


            If DriveNumber = 3 And d.TotalSize < 1099511627776 Then

                Dim drow3 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

                drow3("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt")
                drow3("Server") = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
                drow3("Drive") = DriveName.Remove(1, 2)
                drow3("TotalSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow3("UsedSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024,)
                drow3("RemainingSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024,)
                drow3("GBorTBDrive") = "GB"
                drow3("DriveActiveStatus") = d.IsReady
                dt.Rows.Add(drow3)

            ElseIf DriveNumber = 3 And d.TotalSize >= 1099511627776 And d.TotalSize - d.TotalFreeSpace >= 1099511627776 And d.TotalFreeSpace >= 1099511627776 Then

                Dim drow3 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

                drow3("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt")
                drow3("Server") = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
                drow3("Drive") = DriveName.Remove(1, 2)
                drow3("TotalSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow3("UsedSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow3("RemainingSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow3("GBorTBDrive") = "TB"
                drow3("DriveActiveStatus") = d.IsReady
                dt.Rows.Add(drow3)

            ElseIf DriveNumber = 3 And d.TotalSize >= 1099511627776 And d.TotalSize - d.TotalFreeSpace >= 1099511627776 And d.TotalFreeSpace < 1099511627776 Then

                Dim drow3 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

                drow3("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt")
                drow3("Server") = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
                drow3("Drive") = DriveName.Remove(1, 2)
                drow3("TotalSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow3("UsedSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow3("RemainingSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow3("GBorTBDrive") = "TB"
                drow3("DriveActiveStatus") = d.IsReady
                dt.Rows.Add(drow3)

            ElseIf DriveNumber = 3 And d.TotalSize >= 1099511627776 And d.TotalSize - d.TotalFreeSpace < 1099511627776 And d.TotalFreeSpace >= 1099511627776 Then

                Dim drow3 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

                drow3("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt")
                drow3("Server") = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
                drow3("Drive") = DriveName.Remove(1, 2)
                drow3("TotalSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow3("UsedSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow3("RemainingSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow3("GBorTBDrive") = "TB"
                drow3("DriveActiveStatus") = d.IsReady
                dt.Rows.Add(drow3)

            ElseIf DriveNumber = 3 And d.TotalSize >= 1099511627776 And d.TotalSize - d.TotalFreeSpace < 1099511627776 And d.TotalFreeSpace < 1099511627776 Then

                Dim drow3 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

                drow3("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt")
                drow3("Server") = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
                drow3("Drive") = DriveName.Remove(1, 2)
                drow3("TotalSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024,)
                drow3("UsedSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow3("RemainingSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow3("GBorTBDrive") = "TB"
                drow3("DriveActiveStatus") = d.IsReady
                dt.Rows.Add(drow3)

            End If


            If DriveNumber = 4 And d.TotalSize < 1099511627776 Then

                Dim drow4 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

                drow4("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt")
                drow4("Server") = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
                drow4("Drive") = DriveName.Remove(1, 2)
                drow4("TotalSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow4("UsedSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow4("RemainingSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow4("GBorTBDrive") = "GB"
                drow4("DriveActiveStatus") = d.IsReady
                dt.Rows.Add(drow4)

            ElseIf DriveNumber = 4 And d.TotalSize >= 1099511627776 And d.TotalSize - d.TotalFreeSpace >= 1099511627776 And d.TotalFreeSpace >= 1099511627776 Then

                Dim drow4 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

                drow4("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt")
                drow4("Server") = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
                drow4("Drive") = DriveName.Remove(1, 2)
                drow4("TotalSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024,)
                drow4("UsedSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow4("RemainingSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow4("GBorTBDrive") = "TB"
                drow4("DriveActiveStatus") = d.IsReady
                dt.Rows.Add(drow4)

            ElseIf DriveNumber = 4 And d.TotalSize >= 1099511627776 And d.TotalSize - d.TotalFreeSpace >= 1099511627776 And d.TotalFreeSpace < 1099511627776 Then

                Dim drow4 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

                drow4("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt")
                drow4("Server") = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
                drow4("Drive") = DriveName.Remove(1, 2)
                drow4("TotalSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024,)
                drow4("UsedSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow4("RemainingSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow4("GBorTBDrive") = "TB"
                drow4("DriveActiveStatus") = d.IsReady
                dt.Rows.Add(drow4)

            ElseIf DriveNumber = 4 And d.TotalSize >= 1099511627776 And d.TotalSize - d.TotalFreeSpace < 1099511627776 And d.TotalFreeSpace >= 1099511627776 Then

                Dim drow4 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

                drow4("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt")
                drow4("Server") = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
                drow4("Drive") = DriveName.Remove(1, 2)
                drow4("TotalSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024,)
                drow4("UsedSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow4("RemainingSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow4("GBorTBDrive") = "TB"
                drow4("DriveActiveStatus") = d.IsReady
                dt.Rows.Add(drow4)

            ElseIf DriveNumber = 4 And d.TotalSize >= 1099511627776 And d.TotalSize - d.TotalFreeSpace < 1099511627776 And d.TotalFreeSpace < 1099511627776 Then

                Dim drow4 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

                drow4("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt")
                drow4("Server") = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
                drow4("Drive") = DriveName.Remove(1, 2)
                drow4("TotalSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024,)
                drow4("UsedSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow4("RemainingSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow4("GBorTBDrive") = "TB"
                drow4("DriveActiveStatus") = d.IsReady
                dt.Rows.Add(drow4)

            End If

            If DriveNumber = 5 And d.TotalSize < 1099511627776 Then

                Dim drow5 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

                drow5("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt")
                drow5("Server") = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
                drow5("Drive") = DriveName.Remove(1, 2)
                drow5("TotalSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow5("UsedSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow5("RemainingSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow5("GBorTBDrive") = "GB"
                drow5("DriveActiveStatus") = d.IsReady
                dt.Rows.Add(drow5)


            ElseIf DriveNumber = 5 And d.TotalSize >= 1099511627776 And d.TotalSize - d.TotalFreeSpace >= 1099511627776 And d.TotalFreeSpace >= 1099511627776 Then

                Dim drow5 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

                drow5("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt")
                drow5("Server") = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
                drow5("Drive") = DriveName.Remove(1, 2)
                drow5("TotalSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024,)
                drow5("UsedSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow5("RemainingSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow5("GBorTBDrive") = "TB"
                drow5("DriveActiveStatus") = d.IsReady
                dt.Rows.Add(drow5)

            ElseIf DriveNumber = 5 And d.TotalSize >= 1099511627776 And d.TotalSize - d.TotalFreeSpace >= 1099511627776 And d.TotalFreeSpace < 1099511627776 Then

                Dim drow5 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

                drow5("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt")
                drow5("Server") = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
                drow5("Drive") = DriveName.Remove(1, 2)
                drow5("TotalSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow5("UsedSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow5("RemainingSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow5("GBorTBDrive") = "TB"
                drow5("DriveActiveStatus") = d.IsReady
                dt.Rows.Add(drow5)

            ElseIf DriveNumber = 5 And d.TotalSize >= 1099511627776 And d.TotalSize - d.TotalFreeSpace < 1099511627776 And d.TotalFreeSpace >= 1099511627776 Then

                Dim drow5 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

                drow5("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt")
                drow5("Server") = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
                drow5("Drive") = DriveName.Remove(1, 2)
                drow5("TotalSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024,)
                drow5("UsedSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow5("RemainingSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow5("GBorTBDrive") = "TB"
                drow5("DriveActiveStatus") = d.IsReady
                dt.Rows.Add(drow5)

            ElseIf DriveNumber = 5 And d.TotalSize >= 1099511627776 And d.TotalSize - d.TotalFreeSpace < 1099511627776 And d.TotalFreeSpace < 1099511627776 Then

                Dim drow5 As DataRow = dt.NewRow

                drow5("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt")
                drow5("Server") = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
                drow5("Drive") = DriveName.Remove(1, 2)
                drow5("TotalSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024,)
                drow5("UsedSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalSize / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 - d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow5("RemainingSpace") = FormatNumber(d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
                drow5("GBorTBDrive") = "TB"
                drow5("DriveActiveStatus") = d.IsReady
                dt.Rows.Add(drow5)

            End If
        Next

        ' Write Information to XML file

        Dim day As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy" & Space(1) & "MM" & Space(1) & "dd" & Space(1) & "h" & Space(1) & "mm" & Space(1) & "ss" & Space(1) & "tt")

        Dim path As String = "C:\temp"
        path = IO.Path.Combine(path, "ServerStorageC7L6M72" & Space(1) & day & Space(1) & ".xml")
        dt.WriteXml(path)

    End Sub
    Public Sub UploadXML(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Dim day As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy MM dd h mm ss tt")
        Dim path As String = IO.Path.Combine("C:\temp", "ServerStorageC7L6M72 " & day & " .xml")
        ' Please tell me you're not really using the sa account for this. That's REALLY BAD!
        Dim ServerCheckConnectString = "Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Password=*****;Initial Catalog=ServerDriveStorageChecks;Data Source=localhost;"
        Dim SQL As String = "
INSERT INTO DriveInformation
    (Date, Server, Drive, TotalSpace, UsedSpace, RemainingSpace, GBorTBDrive, DriveActiveStatus)
SELECT 
    MY_XML.DriveInformation.query('Date').value('.', 'DATETIME'),
    MY_XML.DriveInformation.query('Server').value('.', 'VARCHAR(15)'), 
    MY_XML.DriveInformation.query('Drive').value('.', 'VARCHAR(1)'),  
    MY_XML.DriveInformation.query('TotalSpace').value('.', 'NUMERIC(10,2)'), 
    MY_XML.DriveInformation.query('UsedSpace').value('.', 'NUMERIC(10,2)'), 
    MY_XML.DriveInformation.query('RemainingSpace').value('.', 'NUMERIC(10,2)'), 
    MY_XML.DriveInformation.query('GBorTBDrive').value('.', 'VARCHAR(2)'), 
    MY_XML.DriveInformation.query('DriveActiveStatus').value('.', 'VARCHAR(6)')
FROM (
    SELECT CAST(MY_XML AS xml) 
    FROM OPENROWSET (BULK " & path & ", SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(MY_XML)) AS T(MY_XML)
CROSS APPLY MY_XML.nodes('DocumentElement/DriveInformation') AS MY_XML (DriveInformation);"

        Using cn As New SqlConnection(ServerCheckConnectString),
          cmd As New SqlCommand(SQL, cn)

            cn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using ' Connection is closed/disposed here, *even if an exception is thrown*
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Once you clean up the command text you need to actually execute the command. As posted your code won't do anything. Most likely you will want to use ExecuteNonQuery().

Comment: Might be wiser to just pass the whole file as a `varbinary` parameter. But for that the client would need access to it, at the moment you are storing it on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VB.Net SQL string includes an extra comma at the end of the first line, between the initial `SELECT` and `INSERT` commands, that is not part of the original SQL and should not be there, causing SQL Server to see this invalid expression:

```
SELECT * FROM DriveInformation, INSERT INTO ...
```

Remove the "," from that section. But also it doesn't seem you are using this `SELECT` statement at all, and can remove it entirely. If you are using it, and we just don't see that portion of the code, at least put it *after* the `INSERT` command, so the new rows are included with the results.

There are other improvements we can make, as well:

```vb
Public Sub UploadXML(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim day As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy MM dd h mm ss tt")
    Dim path As String = IO.Path.Combine("C:\temp", "ServerStorageC7L6M72 " & day & " .xml")
    ' Please tell me you're not really using the sa account for this. That's REALLY BAD!
    Dim ServerCheckConnectString As String = "Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Password=********;Initial Catalog=ServerDriveStorageChecks;Data Source=localhost;"
    Dim SQL As String = "
INSERT INTO DriveInformation
    (Date, Server, Drive, TotalSpace, UsedSpace, RemainingSpace, GBorTBDrive, DriveActiveStatus)
SELECT 
    MY_XML.DriveInformation.query('Date').value('.', 'DATETIME'), 
    MY_XML.DriveInformation.query('Server').value('.', 'VARCHAR(15)'), 
    MY_XML.DriveInformation.query('Drive').value('.', 'VARCHAR(1)'),  
    MY_XML.DriveInformation.query('TotalSpace').value('.', 'NUMERIC(10,2)'), 
    MY_XML.DriveInformation.query('UsedSpace').value('.', 'NUMERIC(10,2)'), 
    MY_XML.DriveInformation.query('RemainingSpace').value('.', 'NUMERIC(10,2)'), 
    MY_XML.DriveInformation.query('GBorTBDrive').value('.', 'VARCHAR(2)'), 
    MY_XML.DriveInformation.query('DriveActiveStatus').value('.', 'VARCHAR(6)')
FROM (
    SELECT CAST(MY_XML AS xml) 
    FROM OPENROWSET (BULK " & path & ", SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(MY_XML)
) AS T(MY_XML)
CROSS APPLY MY_XML.nodes('DocumentElement/DriveInformation') AS MY_XML (DriveInformation);"

    Using cn  As New SqlConnection(ServerCheckConnectString), _
          cmd As New SqlCommand(SQL, cn)

        cn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using ' Connection is closed/disposed here, *even if an exception is thrown*
End Sub
```

---

One particular pet peeve of mine is this:

```
Dim cn As New SqlConnection
' ...
cn = New SqlConnection(ServerCheckConnectString)
```

... where you declare a variable with `New`, so it also allocates the object, and then the first reference to the variable again assigns a new reference to it. This wastefully allocates an extra object from memory, only to immediately discard it. While it's possible the compiler might detect this and optimize the allocation away, it's often a sign the author lacks a basic understanding of what the code is doing.

---

**Update:**

Having read through the code, I believe this issue is the current time changes between creating the xml file and loading it in the server, so the file name (down to the second) no longer exists. To fix this, you can either save the file name somewhere in memory at the point when you write it to disk, or ask the system for the names of the xml files in your target path.

While I was there, I took a few minutes to consolidate all the IF/Else checks in the final loop down to a **SINGLE SET**, reducing the code considerably:

```vb
Public GBTBBreak As Integer = 1099511627776 
Public GBDivisor As Double = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1.0
Public TBDivisor As Double = GBDivisor * 1024

Public Function FormatForGBTB(input As Integer) As String
    If input < GBTBBreak Then
        Return String.Format("{0,15} {1}", input / GBDivisor, "GB")
    Else
        Return String.Format("{0, 15} {1}", input / TBDivisor, "TB")
    End If
End Function

Public Sub Main()

    Dim dt As New DataTable("DriveInformation")

    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Date"))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Server"))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Drive"))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("TotalSpace"))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("UsedSpace"))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("RemainingSpace"))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("GBorTBDrive"))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("DriveActiveStatus"))

    ' Get information and Write to Console.
    Dim Host As String = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
    Console.WriteLine("Server Name: {0}", Host)
    Console.WriteLine("Date: {0}{1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt"), vbCrLf)


    Dim allDrives() As IO.DriveInfo = IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives()   

    For Each d As IO.DriveInfo In allDrives.Where(Function(dr) dr.IsReady)
        Console.WriteLine(d.Name)
        Console.WriteLine("  Drive type: {0}", d.DriveType)
        Console.WriteLine("  Volume label: {0}", d.VolumeLabel)
        Console.WriteLine("  File system: {0}", d.DriveFormat)
        Console.WriteLine("  Total size of drive:   {0}", FormatForGBTB(d.TotalSize))
        Console.WriteLine("  Total used space:      {0}", FormatForGBTB(d.TotalSize - d.TotalFreeSpace))
        Console.WriteLine("  Total available space: {0}", FormatForGBTB(d.TotalFreeSpace))
    Next

    ' Put Information into DataTable
    For Each d In allDrives
        ' The DriveNumber check was NOT NEEDED, added a bunch of extra code

        Dim divisor As Double = If(d.TotalSize < GBTBBreak, GBDivisor, TBDivisor)

        Dim row As DataRow = dt.NewRow

        row("Date") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt")
        row("Server") = Host
        row("Drive") = d.Name.Remove(1, 2)

        ' There was an issue with the original where the units were
        ' only preserved in the GBorTBDrive column, which was only
        ' based on the TotalSpace column, but the UsedSpace and 
        ' Remaining space columns would still scale without showing
        ' which units they used. Since we're storing the unit
        ' separately, I simplified to always scale with the 
        ' GBorTBColumn. Otherwise, information was lost about 
        ' the actual amount of used vs free space. As an alternative, 
        ' you could include the units with each column again,
        ' as was done in the previous loop.
        row("TotalSpace") = (d.TotalSize / divisor).ToString()
        row("UsedSpace") = ((d.TotalSize-d.TotalFreeSpace) / divisor).ToString()
        row("RemainingSpace") = (d.TotalFreeSpace / divisor).ToString()
        row("GBorTBDrive") = If(d.TotalSize < GBTBBreak, "GB", "TB")
        row("DriveActiveStatus") = d.IsReady
        dt.Rows.Add(row)

    Next

    ' Write Information to XML file

    Dim day As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy MM dd h mm ss tt")
    Dim path As String = IO.Path.Combine("C:\temp", "ServerStorageC7L6M72 " & day & " .xml")
    dt.WriteXml(path)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank all of you for your insight into this question and the helpful responses!  @Joel Coehoorn I do understand that the SA account is not safe practice to use.  I am only using it as a temporary test environment for the time being.  Also I am still fairly new to coding and even newer to SQL functions and queries.  I am working on better optimizing my code and workflow as I gain more experience with coding.  I will post the full code in the next comment below.  Please keep in mind this code hasn't been optimized yet and will appear messy as right now i'm testing for functionality.

Comment: Sorry meant to say `MY_XML.DriveInformation.value('(Date/text())[1]', 'DATETIME')`, etc is simpler code and probably faster. Also would be wise to do `& path.Replace("'", "''")` in case of injection problems.

Comment: @dpresnell90 don't post code into comments. Edit it into the original question.

Comment: Hi @JoelCoehoorn.  Thank you for the information.  I placed the full code within the question and had to remove some of the previous code as my code snippet is too long.  I know that this code needs alot of optimisation which I plan on doing once getting everything functional within the code.  I know its alot of If Then Else Statements as well.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn After adding in your provided information it still didn't function correctly so I know its an error in the coding on my behalf.  Time for debugging galore!

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Thank you very much!  that did the trick and optimised the code greatly!  I upvoted as well as marked the question as answered!